# Android canvas.drawColor throws a null object reference

Tags: android, html-canvas

I have two nearly identical methods, the first to draw a splash screen while assets are loading, and the second to draw all of the assets to the screen.  The first throws a NullPointerException on this line:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
```

Here is my error:

> `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference` 
>   `10-19 21:54:56.042 18973-18973/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.xyz.123.GameView.drawSplash(GameView.java:76)`

Here is my code in full:

```
package com.xyz.123;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    volatile boolean playing;
    Thread gameThread = null;
    private Paint paint;
    private Canvas canvas;
    private SurfaceHolder holder;
    private int screenWidth;
    private int screenHeight;
    private Background1ResourceList background1ResourceList;
    private Background background1;
    private Background background2;
    private Background background3;
    private Context context;
    private SplashScreen splashScreen;

    public GameView(Context context, int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {

        super(context);

        this.context = context;

        this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
        this.screenHeight = screenHeight;

        // Initialize our drawing objects
        holder = getHolder();
        paint = new Paint();

        splashScreen = new SplashScreen(context, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        drawSplash();

        background1ResourceList = new Background1ResourceList();

        background1 = new Background(context,         background1ResourceList.getBackgroundResources(), screenWidth, screenHeight, 0.00f, 0.50f);
        background2 = new Background(context, background1ResourceList.getBackgroundResources(), screenWidth, screenHeight, 0.33f, 0.80f);
        background3 = new Background(context, background1ResourceList.getBackgroundResources(), screenWidth, screenHeight, 0.66f, 1.00f);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {
            update();
            draw();
            control();
        }
    }

    private void update() {
        background1.update();
        background2.update();
        background3.update();
    }

    private synchronized void drawSplash() {
        if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
        //First we lock the area of memory we will be drawing to
        holder.getSurface();
        canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        // rub out the last frame
        canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        // draw the backgrounds
        splashScreen.draw(canvas, paint);
        // unlock and draw the scene
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        } else {
            System.out.println("surface not valid");
        }
    }

    private synchronized void draw() {
        if (holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            //First we lock the area of memory we will be drawing to
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            // rub out the last frame
            canvas.drawColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            // draw the backgrounds
            background1.draw(canvas, paint);
            background2.draw(canvas, paint);
            background3.draw(canvas, paint);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        playing = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the canvas is null is because I'm trying to get a canvas from within the constructor of the GameView (which is a surface view).

I moved the call to drawSplash method into the run method immediately before the game loop and it works perfectly.